# If statements baffling my head can someone advise

Tags: python-3.x

Im a complete beginner to Python and trying to learn. I cant work out the last part of my extremely basic code. If the user enters "No" I want the program to execute the goodbye part of the code:

```
a = ("Yes")
b = ("No")
name = input("What is your name?\n")
age = input("How old are you?\n")
country = input("Where are you from?\n")
print("Hi " + name + " " + "I see you are " + age + " " + "and you were born in " + country)

answer = input("Do you want to play a game?\n")

print("awesome")

if a == "Yes":
  print("OK, lets play...")
  
else:
  b == "No"
  print("Thank you for your time, goodbye")
```

When I run the above I get the following:

What is your name?
Paul
How old are you?
49
Where are you from?
UK
Hi Paul I see you are 49 and you were born in UK
Do you want to play a game?
No
awesome
OK, lets play...

If the user enters "No" I'm expecting the code to return "Thank you for your time, goodbye". But as you can see this isn't the case!

Please advise..

Comment: see the first line of your code, which sets `a` to `"Yes"`

Comment: You're setting `a = ("Yes")` in the first line of code, so `if a == "Yes"` will always be true, because you're getting the user input into `answer`, not `a`. You also `print("awesome")` before you would even check the user's input. Your `else:` makes no sense, either - you test `b == "No"`, which will also always be true because of the second line of your code, and you throw away the result of the comparison anyway. You should read your code.

Comment: Your if and else statements should check the value of answer rather than a or b

Comment: Finally got it to work. I am brand new to learning how to code so please forgive me for asking what is clearly something very simple to those who know. Thanks for the help, much appreciated.